# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined. (posted by a newbie)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compiler-errors

Hi I am new to AngularJs. I am getting error:

> " Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined. "

I tried to find the error but couldn't figure out. Thanks. 
the code i wrote was:-

```
<html ng-app="firstApp">

<body ng-controller="firstController">
  Enter 1st name:<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
  <br/> Enter last Name:<input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
  <br>
  <button ng-click="getFullName()">Get Full Name</button>
  <hr/> Full Name:<label ng-bind="fullName"></label>
  <script scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("firstApp", []);
    app.controller("firstController", function($scope) {
      $scope.firstName = "";
      $scope.lastName = "";
      $scope.fullName = "";
      $scope.getFullName = function() {
        $scope.fullName = $scope.firstName + "" + $scope.lastName;
      };
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are new to Angular, try to be familiar with Angular 2+. Currently you are using 1+.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typpo, it should be src instead of scr

**`DEMO`**

```html
<html ng-app="firstApp">
<body ng-controller="firstController">
Enter 1st name:<input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/>
<br/>
Enter last Name:<input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/>
<br>
<button ng-click="getFullName()">Get Full Name</button>
<hr/>
Full  Name:<label ng-bind="fullName"></label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app= angular.module("firstApp",[])
    app.controller("firstController",function($scope)
    {
        $scope.firstName="";
        $scope.lastName="";
        $scope.fullName="";
        $scope.getFullName=function()
        {
            $scope.fullName=$scope.firstName+""+$scope.lastName;    
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting executed before the angular library is loaded. Sometimes libraries loaded from cloud takes time to load in the browser.

Please take the angular library locally and try to load a file from local.